# Bootstrap 3 - moving a column on MD

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, push, pull

I've had a look at the similar questions but to no avail.

I have 6 columns across a footer. When it reaches down to the MD range I need the first column to move either to the last or preferably penultimate position. I have been trying to use push and pull classes but after an hour I thought it best to maybe just ask a question.

```
<div class="footerColumns">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-6 signUp">col 1<br>Sign up &amp; Follow us</div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-6 corpBranch">col 2-5<br>corporate &amp; branches</div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-6 corpBranch">col 2-5<br>corporate &amp; branches</div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-6 corpBranch">col 2-5<br>corporate &amp; branches</div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-6 corpBranch">col 2-5<br>corporate &amp; branches</div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-6 payAccred">col 6<br>Payment\Accreds</div>
</div>
```

```css
<style>
    .footerColumns * {text-align: center; }
    .footerColumns > div {padding: 5px; }
    .signUp {background-color: CadetBlue; }
    .corpBranch {background-color: BlanchedAlmond;}
    .payAccred {background-color: Chocolate; }
</style>
```

In LG range(as desired)
[image: In LG range]

In MD range (currently)
[image]

I need the blue column 1 to position before the amber column 6 on everything from MD down, like this:
[image]

Many thanks in advance for assistance!
EDIT: I'm going to try doing mobile first, just for a laugh :-)

Answer (score 0):

Doing mobile first did the trick. Don't worry, have slapped myself in head, verily.

```html
<div class="footerColumns">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-push-2 col-md-3 col-sm-6 corpBranch">col 2-5<br>corporate &amp; branches</div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-push-2 col-md-3 col-sm-6 corpBranch">col 2-5<br>corporate &amp; branches</div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-push-2 col-md-3 col-sm-6 corpBranch">col 2-5<br>corporate &amp; branches</div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-push-2 col-md-3 col-sm-6 corpBranch">col 2-5<br>corporate &amp; branches</div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-pull-8 col-sm-6 signUp">col 1<br>Sign up &amp; Follow us</div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-6 payAccred">col 6<br>Payment\Accreds</div>
</div>
```

[image: LG RANGE]

[image: MD range]

[image: SM range]

[image: XS range]